# Crontab not running commands listed in /etc/crontab

Tags: cron

so I've got some `nfexpire` commands that crontab was meant to run listed in `/etc/crontab`. They have been working fine for some time but recently they've stopped running at all. Every other job runs, just not the ones in `/etc/crontab`.
I have checked that the crontab daemon is running by exectuing `systemctl status crond`

I have checked `/var/log/cron` and `/var/log/messages` as well as running `journalctl` in search for any errors but haven't found anything.

I have made sure that the commands are executable via the terminal, so the problem lies somewhere in crontab.

The `/etc/crontab` file:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root

# For details see man 4 crontabs

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name  command to be executed
  
30 03 01 * * nfexpire -e "something"
30 03 01 * * nfexpire -e "something"
30 03 01 * * nfexpire -e "something"
30 03 01 * * nfexpire -e "something"
30 03 01 * * nfexpire -e "something"
30 03 01 * * nfexpire -e "something"
```

Oh and I've made sure that there's a newline at the end.

Maybe there's an issue with permissions?

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 891 Feb  6  2020 /etc/crontab
```

However it ran with those settings for a few months without any problems so I don't know if any of this should be changed.

Additional info

System: Centos 7

Kernel: 3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64

Comment: What user should run those commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a matter of syntax. In this file you should add additional field, a *user name*:

```
30 03 01 * * username nfexpire -e "something"
```

Then, the cron job will be run as `username`.

Additional considerations.

- Are there all jobs that start *simultaneously*? Not too good. In that case, better make a script that runs them all and have a single job.
- Better don't edit /etc/crontab at all. Use drop-directories `/etc/cron.d` and other `/etc/cron.*` (put executable scripts there) for root-owned jobs which start time is not very important, and what is only important is the periodicity of the job (daily, weekly and so on). Use dedicated user crontabs for user-run jobs: `crontab -e -u username`. There you omit the "username" field, as the job will run under whoever this particular crontab belongs to. In any case, this way no system update will disturb your crontab entry.
- Consider the use of `systemd` timers.

Answer (score -1):

Your /etc/crontab file needs `root` in front of each command.

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root

# For details see man 4 crontabs

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name  command to be executed
  
30 03 01 * * root nfexpire -e "something"
30 03 01 * * root nfexpire -e "something"
30 03 01 * * root nfexpire -e "something"
30 03 01 * * root nfexpire -e "something"
30 03 01 * * root nfexpire -e "something"
30 03 01 * * root nfexpire -e "something"
```

Comment: The issue is, as you have correctly identified, the missing user name. This is also pointed out in the accepted answer. Can you elaborate on why the user needs to be root specifically? If so, then this information may be better suited as an addition to the accepted answer.

Comment: Good point. To clarify, if the OP's intent is to modify /etc/crontab specifically (i.e. the system wide crontab) rather than a user-specific crontab, then the logged-in user must have write access to /etc/crontab, and the user-name field does not necessarily have to be `root`.